# Whats wrong with this list of servers in my bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax-error

I am writing a simple bash script (`checkServs.sh`) that will ssh into a list of servers and perform a health check on them.

I keep getting errors on the following line:

```
SERVERS=(blah1.example.com blah2.example.com blah3.example.com blah4.example.com)
```

Error is:

```
checkServs.sh: 3: checkServs.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've checked online examples and this seems correct, isn't it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`?  The problem seems to be that the shell you're using is not recognizing the array notation.  Is `/bin/sh` actually a link to a different shell?  (`/bin/sh` as a link to `/bin/bash` appears to recognize the array assignment.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, But as a link to `dash` it doesn't, and produces the same syntax error. Maybe that's it. I'll update my answer with that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the syntax error, but this should work:

```
SERVERS="blah1.example.com blah2.example.com blah3.example.com blah4.example.com"
for server in $SERVERS
do
    echo $server
done
```

---

**EDIT**: As noted by Jonathan Leffler in a comment, maybe you are not running the script with `bash`. Other shells, such as `dash`, may not recognize the array syntax. If that's the case, you *can* do:

```
SERVERS=(blah1.example.com blah2.example.com blah3.example.com blah4.example.com)
for i in $(seq 0 3)
do
    echo ${SERVERS[$i]}
done
```

But if you just want to loop through the names and run an SSH command (ie if having an array won't provide useful functionality), the first method is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote server probably calls a different shell when executing commands. Try to add bash -c to your arguments:

```
ssh user@server bash -c "<your commands>"
```

Or:

```
ssh user@server bash < yourscript.sh  ## None in yourscript.sh must read input though.
```

Answer (score -1):

An opening parenthesis starts a subshell, which is not a correct thing to have on the right side of an equals sign. It expects a string expression, not a command.

Quotation marks are used to keep a string expression together.

Comment: This is not correct. In the case of an assignment in `bash`, it makes the variable an array. In POSIX shells that don't support arrays (eg `dash`), it's a syntax error.